# How to get the indexed list sequences from a fasta file?

Tags: python, fasta

I compared two fasta files (with different length of sequence and names) and got the shared sequence name into a list. I tried to get the sequences with the names in the list.

file1:

SRR3350720.1

atccaaccactaaagcagtggtatcaacgcagagtacatggggacattcagtgattatggcatgcactgggtc

SRR3350720.3

caggtgcaggtggtgcagtctggggctgaggtgaagaagcctggctcctcggtgaagatctcatgcaaggctt

SRR3350720.5

caggtccagctggtacagtctggggctgaggtgaagaagcctggggcctcagtgaaggtctcctgcaaggttg

SRR3350720.6

caggtgcagttccagccgtggggcgcaggactgttgaagccttcggagaccctgtccctcacctgcgctgtct

list = ['SRR3350720.1','SRR3350720.5']

I tried the script in python.

```
import HTSeq
fasta_file = HTSeq.FastaReader('file1.fasta', 'r')
for line in fasta_file:
    for ls in list:
        if str(line.name) == ls:
            print str(line)
```

But for each NGS sequencing, I have million sequences and 10 thousands of sequence id in the list. How to improve the scripts and make efficiently to handle data.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is mostly [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound), i.e. it won't help you to parallelize the code on multiple CPUs. The best way to accelerate it is to copy the fasta to a SSD or straight to the memory.

Concerning your code, assuming your sequence ids are stored in a list called seq_ids.

```
import HTSeq
seq_ids = ['SRR3350720.1','SRR3350720.5']
fasta_file = HTSeq.FastaReader('file1.fasta', 'r')
for read in fasta_file:
    if str(read.name) in seq_ids:
        print str(read)
```

Explantion:

```
str(read.name) in seq_ids
```

check if the `read.name` is in your list and only then prints the read itself.

In your code you are looping over the search list for entry read, even if one read matches you are still continuing with your loop.

---

If you just need the header and one line of sequence, try using [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)

```
grep -A1 -w -f list.txt file1.fasta
```

-w print the matching line

-A1 print line after the match

-f use the patterns from list.txt

file1.fasta the file which is searched